# How to explicitly terminate http connection from server with no response header

Tags: java, servlets

I am developing a server simulator for one of my client application. I am using GlassFish server. I have to simulate a http connection terminate condition in my server application.

Is there a way by which I can explicitly terminate a connection from server side such that client does not receive any response header. Currently I have tried many options like closing the response outputStream. But in every case a http 200 OK message is delivered to the client application. I would like to consume the http-request and do not want to return anything to the client.

I am using a simple conrtroller servlet and had overridden `doGet()` and `doPost()` functions.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have difficulty persuading an appserver to do this, they're designed to be robust.

I suggest taking a look at [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), which is an embeddable and highly configurable HTTP/servlet framework which you can use as alternative to the appserver's built-in support. There's a good chance you'll be able to configure it with a customized connection handler, and hopefully perform your specific connection terminations.

Comment: Yes, Jetty with a custom connection handler is likely the way to go.